# OperationalError: no such column: a

Tags: python, database, api, sqlite, rest

I'm trying to get the value of `name=a` and get the data there
But I'm getting

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: a
```

```
@app.route('/editform/<_name>')
def editform(_name):
    db = sql.connect("database.db")

    cursor = db.cursor()    

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM students WHERE name= %s' %_name)
```

Comment: Thank you I solved : cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM students WHERE name= "%s"' %_name)

Comment: Don't do that for the reasons I mentioned in my answer! Someone might simply type `http://yourwebsite.com/editform/"; DROP TABLE students;` in their browser and your SQL becomes `SELECT * FROM students WHERE name=""; DROP TABLE students;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you use string formatting to substitute `%s` with the value of `_name`, ending up with

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE name= a
```

Note that `a` here is interpreted to be a column name because it is not between quotes (i.e. `"a"`).

Don't use string formatting for SQL statements as you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use the proper [placeholder syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders):

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM students WHERE name=?', (_name,))
```